# Entering multiple values into a url post

Tags: java, android

Working on taking a input from users `EditText` and formatting it to go into a url `$_GET` so I can save it to a mysql database. As of right now the app will only store the first value in each `EditText` fields.

If someone could give me a pointer as to what i am doing wrong that would be sweet!

```
public class NewIdea extends Activity{
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
private List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
private Button button;
private EditText idea, des;
private Object mPassword;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_screen);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateIdea);
        idea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inId);
        des = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inDis);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
                //for (int i = 0; i < des.length(); i++ ) {
                //params.append(des.getText().toString());}

                String   mUsername = idea.getText().toString();
                String mPassword = des.getText().toString();

                String answer = null;
                StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder(mPassword);
                for(int i = 0; i < des.getText().length(); i++) {
                  params.append(des + "%" +i) ;
                  answer = params.toString();
                }
                tryLogin(mUsername, answer);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void tryLogin(String idea, String answer)
    {           
       HttpURLConnection connection;
       OutputStreamWriter request = null;

        URL url = null;   
        String response = null;         
        String parameters = "?ideaname="+idea+"&description="+answer; 
        try
        {
            url = new URL("http://"server"/PHP/create_idea.php"+ parameters);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");    
            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();            
            String line = parameters;               
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append("%" + line);
            }
            // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
            response = sb.toString();
            // You can perform UI operations here
            Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             
            isr.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // Error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Usernames and password, working with GET request is never appreciated, as GET appends data into URL which is visible publically. it is recomended to use POST request. you can post your data to server using this method, simply add your data into NameaValuePair and add to as an entity to post request. on server side you can get data using

```
$_POST['key']
```

try this method

```
public static String HitServerPOST(String url,List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
    String response = null;

    try {
        postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```

and calling will be like

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1","value1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2","value2"));
String response = HitServerPOST(SERVER_URL,nameValuePairs);
```

Comment: where do i reference `String mPassword = des.getText().toString(); in the ArrayList?`   Its not really a password, i re-used code, it is just a field full of txt. but if post works better

Comment: nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwordkey",mPassword));
even if its not password, still POST request is better than GET

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO thank you sir, lots of people helped me on this problem, your the first one to explain a way i could understand! it works